# How can I make balance by using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

My controller:

```
$table = CashBook::select(
  DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'),
  DB::raw('SUM(amountOut) as dr'),
  DB::raw('SUM(amountIN) as cr')
)->groupBy('date')
->get();

return view('cashbook.cashbook')->with(['table' => $table]);
```

The table which I want to implement:

```
@foreach($table as $row)
  <tr>
    <td>{{date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->date))}}</td>
    <td>TK. {{number_format($row->cr,2)}}</td>
    <td>TK. {{number_format($row->dr,2)}}</td>
    @php
    $tbalance = $row->cr - $row->dr;
    @endphp
    <td>TK. {{number_format($tbalance,2)}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I am trying to make balance of **debit** and **credit**. But it can not possible to me to take the `<td>TK. {{number_format($tbalance,2)}}</td>` in an array and add the current balance with the previous one.

Comment: update code like.. `$tbalance = $tbalance + ($row->cr - $row->dr);` Don't forget to initialize the `$tbalance` with 0.

Comment: Thank you so much. Love you man.